# iOS app rejected because app not provided In App Purchase

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, review

I am developing an app for a client, app can show media content(PDF,text,Video) from account on website. On the site you can buy extended account for create own materials, but this feauture not connected with app. Apple rejected app because it not provided in-app-purchase. but this feauture not required in app. I wrote a reply and explained, but app rejected again.What are some ways not to implement the built-in app purchase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple rarely allow exceptions for this. Even companies like Amazon don't get this past reviewers.

Your only real options are to create an IAP or remove the purchase options from the site when viewed from the app.

Comment: Ok @StephenDarlington, I just got rejected by the same reason. My problem is that I have activation code, which is not connected with purchase - it is just categorizing domain in which user will create database, so how to appeal in front of Apple about that?

Comment: @new2ios Tell them what it's used for. Maybe provide an activation code so they can see.

Comment: 10x for advice, @StephenDarlington. I already provided activation code. It is funny, because this is not the first version and this feature is from the very first publication :). I will try to explain to them.